# How to move focus on input when gn-model is true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have div object and input field which placed on hidden form. When I click div, the form shows and focus must be moved to input field.

```
<div ng-click="createForm = true">
    Create item
</div>

<div ng-show="createForm">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" ng-blur="createForm = false">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I found solution with using directive, but it doesn't work.

```
app.directive('focusOn', function() {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.$on(true, function(e){
            elem[0].focus();
        });
        scope.$on(attr.focusOn, function(e) {
            elem[0].focus();
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: I used focus-on="createForm" with directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not applied the directive?

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="createForm = false" focus-on="createForm">
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/gj9xnhzg/5/) JSFiddle

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-click="createForm = true">
        Create item
    </div>

    <div ng-show="createForm">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" ng-blur="createForm = false" focus-on="createForm">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive('focusOn', function() {
    return {
        limit: 'A',
        scope: {
            focusOn: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.$watch("focusOn", function(e){
                elem[0].focus();
            });
        }
    }
});

app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.createForm = false;
}]);
```

Comment: The example works right. I transformed my source code as in the example but it doesn't work. Focus doesn't move to the input. What could be the reason?